# Docker & Python, Speed up when your requirements.pip list is huge?

Tags: python, django, docker

Say you have a rather large requirements.pip

when you modify a requirements.pip, it takes ages to build Docker image because it has to download and install all packages in `requirements.pip`

Is there a way to speed up the docker image building process when you modify a length `requirements.pip` ?

MY docker

```
....




 COPY ./momsite/requirements.pip /requirements.pip
 RUN pip install -r /requirements.pip \
   && rm -rf /root/.cache

 COPY ./momsite /app/momsite

 COPY ./compose/production/web/etc /etc

 COPY ./compose/production/web/start.sh /
 RUN chmod +x /start.sh


 WORKDIR /app
 RUN chown www-data:www-data /app/momsite/reload

 CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

requirements.pip

```
 amqp==2.1.4
 anyjson==0.3.3
 apns2==0.3.0
 argh==0.24.1
 arrow==0.5.4
 asgi-redis==0.14.1
 asgiref==3.2.3
 asn1crypto==0.22.0
 astroid==1.2.1
 async-timeout==3.0.1
 attrs==19.3.0
 autobahn==19.10.1
 Automat==0.7.0
 autopep8==1.2.1
 awscli==1.10.46
 Babel==2.3.4
 BabelDjango==0.2.2
 backcall==0.1.0
 backports-abc==0.4
 backports.csv==1.0.7
 backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
 backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
 bcdoc==0.12.2
 beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
 billiard==3.5.0.2
 bleach==2.1.1
 boto==2.42.0
 boto3==1.9.146
 botocore==1.12.146
 braintree==3.24.0
 cachetools==3.1.0
 celery==4.0.2
 certifi==2018.11.29
 cffi==1.10.0
 channels==2.3.1
 chardet==3.0.4
 cluster==1.1.2
 colorama==0.3.3
 confusable-homoglyphs==3.2.0
 constantly==15.1.0
 contextlib2==0.4.0
 coreapi==2.3.3
 coreschema==0.0.4
 cron-descriptor==1.2.5
 croniter==0.3.12
 cryptography==2.8
 cssselect==0.9.1
 cssutils==1.0.1
 cycler==0.10.0
 Cython==0.24
 daphne==2.3.0
 dateutils==0.6.6
 decorator==4.1.2
 defusedxml==0.5.0
 Delorean==0.4.1
 derpconf==0.7.3
 diff-match-patch==20121119
 dj-database-url==0.3.0
 dj-email-url==0.0.4
 Django==2.2.5
 django-absolute==0.3
 django-admin-rangefilter==0.3.8
 django-advanced-filters==1.1.1
 django-annoying==0.9.0
 django-appconf==1.0.2
 django-autocomplete-light==3.3.5
 -e git://github.com/justinmayer/django-autoslug.git@4dc75083d84265e019a900d636273c731457193d#egg=django_autoslug
 django-avatar==2.0
 django-baton==1.3.6
 django-bower==5.0.1
 django-braces==1.13.0
 django-cache-url==1.0.0
 django-cacheops==3.2.1
 django-categories==1.6.1
 django-celery-results==1.0.1
 django-classy-tags==0.5
 django-compat==1.0.15
 django-configurations==0.8
 django-constance==2.0.0
 django-cors-headers==0.12
 django-countries==3.4.1
 django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
 django-dashing==0.3
 django-db-readonly==0.3.2
 django-debug-panel==0.8.3
 django-debug-toolbar==2.0
 django-debug-toolbar-line-profiler==0.4.0

... total 383 line
```

Comment: parse the requirements file and pip install yourself? Would that work?

Comment: Show us your `Dockerfile` and requirements.

Comment: I added docker file and requirements

Comment: Haven't tried this myself, and not sure if this would work or if this is a good idea; you can try binding site-packages directory to a host directory as a volume while running the container, so at each build docker would use the same directory and would skip existing packages.

Comment: Can you split your application into smaller pieces or have less infrastructure, so it becomes more manageable?  In the fraction you’ve shown it include both RabbitMQ and Celery, for example, and you could standardize on just one job queue; or if some of the AWS handling is only done in asynchronous tasks, don’t include boto in your main Web server container.

Comment: You can mount your docker hosts pip cache directory in the container. I'm not sure if it is easy with pip but it should be doable with pipenv.

An alternative: Use a private python package registry like nexus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better alternative

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
export COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1
```

put following line as the first line of Dockerfile .
`# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental`

I lost where I found this..

end result is that, your requirements package is cached (once downloaded, cached version will be used on next build)

Comment: Would be nice if you explain what that does.

Comment: yeah i tried to , but couldn't find the doc I consulted.. probably in the future..

Answer (score 2):

You can divide by yourself in different files the requirements that are less likely to change and those that are most likely to change.

Then you have two different `RUN` stages like

```
RUN pip install -r less_likely_to_change.txt
RUN pip install -r most_likely_to_change.txt
```

This will create a layer where you have most of your requirements, and therefore, you are speeding up the process because you won't be changing `less_likely_to_change.txt` so often.